# nginx caching static json response with different languages

Tags: nginx, caching, backend

Backend server `api json` response have multiple languages (en,ru,cn etc..). It's available to cache if response different in size or different content? i'm trying return static response faster in depends on language.

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/api-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=api_cache:200m max_size=2g inactive=2h;
```

my location.

```
location /api/payment-service/customer/categories { 
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires;
    proxy_hide_header Pragma;
    expires 1h;
    proxy_cache_lock on;
    proxy_cache api_cache;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 1h;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    }
```